# Chrome or computer program that records the HTML of websites I visit

Tags: windows, html, chrome, archiving

I'm looking for a program that will automatically record the content of every page I visit and save the HTML locally.

I am fine with a Windows program or a Chrome add-in that does this. I remember reading something about a Mac OS program that did this a while ago but I don't remember the name.

Comment: What is your goal while doing this? Some offline archive? Some statistics?

Comment: Offline archive so I have a history of pages I viewed in the past. That way I can search through my web history more than just URL and page title